# Accessing Facebook's Info and Ads

Tags: facebook, ads

I was just wondering if its possible to get some data from a Facebook page's "Info and Ads" tab via API.
"Info and Ads" has been launched some month ago, but I couldn't find any documentation in Facebook's API about it.

You can access a page's Info and Ads with this link:
https://www.facebook.com/[PageUsername]/ads

Comment: If there is an API it will be listed on https://developers.facebook.com/docs . Pretty sure it doesn't exists yet.

Comment: Those pages are for Facebook users to get an overview of how a page advertises on Facebook. But they don’t provide any API for that, so that other businesses could sniff around what the competition is doing in an automated …